# How can you disable the OpenDNS address bar search hijack?

Tags: search, opendns

OpenDNS hijacks keywords that you type into the address bar and redirects those searches to their own search interfaces that pulls in Google results and their own ads.

This is really the only thing that I do not like about OpenDNS, is there a way to disable this behavior?

**Note:** if I disable the OpenDNS proxy it also seems to disable content filtering which is one of the main reasons I have OpenDNS enabled on my network.  So that doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Comment: I switched to running my own internal DNS server on my LAN because of the hijackery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Firefox addon provides a good solution (for Firefox anyway).  In the options for the addon you can choose Bing, Google, Yahoo, or Google I'm Feeling Lucky.

Addon Link: [Feeling Lucky Fixer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7993)

Answer (score 3):

I think this SF answer for [**Tracking all DNS calls within a network**](https://serverfault.com/questions/51951/tracking-all-dns-calls-within-a-network/51956#51956) would help you.

Login to OpenDNS, click through

- **Dashboard**,

  - **Settings**,

    - **Advanced Settings**, and,

      - Uncheck **Enable typo correction**
      - Apply
    - Content filtering (these controls are in a different path)

Moreover, like I added in the comment, I have a feeling the Serverfault answer also fits here (OpenDNS is probably not the problem).

Comment: This will disable OpenDNS content filtering, though, which the original poster wanted to avoid.

Comment: @arathorn, content filtering is differently handled, this is just typo correction. Moreover, I feel that this is more of a browser effect rather than OpenDNS. Adding the content filtering path in the answer for reference.

Comment: @nik: That's what I would think also, but try it for yourself (I just verified it) -- disabling the typo correction will turn off the content filtering features also.

Comment: @nik: Here's what you'll see on the Content Filtering page after disabling Typo Correction: http://www-files.opendns.com/dashboard/img/placeholder_filtering.gif

Comment: @arathorn, Ok, that was news to me. Never tried it myself. But, learned something now. However, do you think that the OP needs to look at browser settings rather than OpenDNS? I looked some more and came up with this link http://www.labnol.org/software/browsers/prevent-opendns-google-redirects-firefox-address-bar-ie/2662/,,, Don't know if its validated.

Comment: @nik, I think the second solution you linked to in your comments is old information.  It doesn't seem to work anymore.  I have set both Firefox and Internet explorer as described in that article and it has had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you add

```
127.0.0.2   guide.opendns.com
```

To your hosts file (usually in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc in windows)

Then when it tries to redirect you to the hijacking page at guide.opendns.com it will try to go to 127.0.0.2 which presumably doesn't exist. And your browser should give you the normal response for not finding a domain (I tried it on my machine and it works okay).

Comment: This almost works.  It results in an error page when you perform an address bar search instead of taking you to your default search engine.